# How to Solve Simple ODEs Using Thrust and odeint in C++

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, odeint, runge-kutta

I'm trying to create a simple program to become familiar with Thrusts's GPU computational ability and odeint's ODE solving capability. I would like to be able to solve simple ODEs (i.e. dy/dx = 3x^2y) using the Runge-Kutta method on the GPU in the hopes of moving on to more complex problems later on. I am able to do this with relative ease using just odeint:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<double> state_type;

void sys( state_type &y, state_type &dydx, double x){
    dydx[0] = 3*x*x*y[0];                           // dydx = 3*x^2*y
}

int main(){
    state_type y(3);
    runge_kutta4< state_type > rk4;
    y[0] = 2;                                       // y0 = 2

    double x = 1;                                   // x0 = 1
    double h = 0.1;                                 // h = 0.1
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++,x+=h){
        rk4.do_step(sys,y,x,h);
        cout << "(";
        cout << x+h;
        cout << ",";
        cout << y[0]; 
        cout << ")";
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I'm having trouble, however, understanding how thrust would come into play. Most of the online resources I've come across feature the Lorenz parameter study as an example, but I feel this is too advanced for my current level.

I understand the concept of device and host vectors but I don't understand how my problem would be adapted to be solved using the GPU. From my own research I've been able to solve simple algebraic (non-differential) equations using CUDA (not thrust). However, combining my knowledge of odeint and thrust is proving to be more difficult than I had anticipated.

In particular, I am confused about:

1) Adapting the Runge-Kutta stepper

2) Adapting the system function itself (dydx = 3*x*x*y[0] in this example).

3) Including both odeint and Thrust/boost directories into the program

I apologize if this question is too basic or asking too much; I am new to StackOverflow and have not yet learned all the "question-asking" protocol nor how much I should try to solve the problem by myself.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit confusing. If you want to use GPUs you usually have large systems of differential equations. Having only three variables is usually not enough. One single instruction on a GPU is slow but it can do many operations in parallel during one instruction. Thrust is designed to handle large data structures like vectors with many entries on a GPU.

To answer your questions in short you need to

1. add the `thrust_algebra` and the `thrust_operations` to the definition of you RK stepper
2. implement the system function with thrust which is the most difficult step, and
3. add `#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>` and `#include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/thrust.hpp>` to your source files. Of course you also need to link against the CUDA libraries and compile everything with `nvcc`. There is makefile in the examples directory of odeint showing how this works.